# Match everything after AB

Tags: regex, string

I have a string:

```
readiness/dir ABTrickToTrade
```

I want to match everything after `AB`. So I want the output to be `TrickToTrade`.

So far the regex I have come up with matches the whole of `ABTrickToTrade`:

```
/(AB(.*))/g
```

How do I get it to match everything after and not the whole thing?

Comment: I have been using http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the language/tool you are using.  For the above, most regex engines will create backreferences for `ABTrickToTrade` and `TrickToTrade` as `1` and `2` respectively.  In fact, you don't need the outer parentheses.  In JavaScript, for example:

```
matches = str.match(/AB(.*)/);
matches[1]; // TrickToTrade
```

It seems that regexr.com doesn't support capturing parentheses out of the box (at least not from what I see), but other sites do: http://rubular.com/r/gbZ7NAoNeA